# X11 over ssh error: can't open display

Tags: centos, ssh, x11, sshd

I have a desktop and a server both running CentOS 7.5 and I run `ssh -X` from desktop to the server. After connection is made `~/.Xauthority` file is written and I have

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$ xauth list
host.example.com/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
host.example.com:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

but running `xclock` gives `Error: Can't open display` in two minutes. Using `ssh -Y` makes no difference. In `sshd_config` I have

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Setting `X11UseLocalhost no` does not fix the problem. `ss -l | grep 6010` has an empty output.

I also have a different server where forwarding X from the same desktop works as it should. Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to access the root user first?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. With the same result.

Comment: Does `ssh -vvX user@host` provide any useful error messages?

Comment: @RubberStamp: No. It could provide if the problem was on the desktop side, but it is on the server one. There are 2 important messages there: `Authentication succeeded (publickey).` and `Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing`